# How to configure MaTeX correctly under the environment of TeXLive2019

Tags: latex, matex

I downloaded and installed MaTeX from [here](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX).

I installed texlive2019.And  I configured Matex as follows, but there was a strange error:

```
ConfigureMaTeX[
 "pdfLaTeX" -> "D:\\texlive\\2019\\bin\\win32\\pdflatex.exe", 
 "Ghostscript" -> "D:\\texlive\\2019\\tlpkg\\tlgs\\bin\\gswin32c.exe"]
```

*File::badfile: The specified argument  should be a valid string or File.*

```
MaTeX["\\int x \\, dx = \\frac{x^2}{2} + \\text{const.}"]
```

*MaTeX::gserr: Error while running Ghostscript.
GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Can't find initialization file gs_init.ps.*

I want to know the cause of the error report and how to solve it.

Comment: Try MaTeX@.....

Comment: have you read this? https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/102478498

Comment: Have you tested if your TeXLive installation work?

Comment: @vipa My texlive2019 can compile Chinese PDF. I think this error is probably caused by the slow update speed of Matex and the new change of texlive2019.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through this [link](https://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/tex/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=2230), I found the cause of similar problems:

> > gswin32c -h としてみると，
>
> TeX Live に入っている Ghostscript は，直接「gswin32c」というコマンドで呼び出すことを想定していません。
>   あくまでそれは TeX と一緒に使うためのものなので，「rungs」という名前で呼び出すことになっていて，
>   外部ツールから呼び出すことはサポート外と書かれています。
>   tlpkg フォルダの中の tlgs/README.TEXLIVE を読んでください。Web 上で読むならここですね。

Translate this into English through Google translate as follows:

> Ghostscript included in TeX Live is not supposed to be called directly with the command "gswin32c".
>
> It is only for use with TeX, so it is called as "rungs", and calling
>   from an external tool is not supported.
>
> Read TLGS / readme.texlive in the tlpkg folder. It's here if you read on the web.

I found out how to correctly configure Matex in the environment of texlive2019 as follows:

```
<< MaTeX`
ClearMaTeXCache[];
(*MaTeX/tutorial/ConfiguringMaTeX*)
MaTeX`Developer`ResetConfiguration[]
ConfigureMaTeX[
 "pdfLaTeX" -> "D:\\texlive\\2019\\bin\\win32\\xelatex.exe", 
 "Ghostscript" -> "D:\\texlive\\2019\\bin\\win32\\rungs.exe"]
MaTeX["\\ce{2H2 + O3 ->T[\\text{燃烧}] 2H2O}", 
 "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}", 
   "\\usepackage{ctex}"}, FontSize -> 20]
```

[image]

We can also download the independent Ghostscript from [here](https://ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) and configure Matex after installation:

```
ConfigureMaTeX[
 "pdfLaTeX" -> "D:\\texlive\\2019\\bin\\win32\\xelatex.exe", 
 "Ghostscript" -> "C:\\gs\\gs9.50\\bin\\gswin32c.exe"]
```

In this way, the correct output can also be obtained.